# Flask expire objects after due date

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a flask application and I want to make some of my objects expire after their due date.

To explain further, my models have `advertise_date`, `expiration_date` and `status` and they take the duration in `__init__` method.

At the beginning all instances of models are in *'valid'* status, but I want my application to make objects expire (change status attribute to *'expired'*) after their due date automatically.

The code is:

```
class Survey: 
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    advertise_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    expiration_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    status = db.Column (db.String(20), nullable = False)

    def __init__ (self, duration):
        self.status = "valid"
        self.advertise_date = datetime.now()
        self.expiration_date = self.advertise_date + timedelta (days = duration)
```

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: You can create several kinds of background jobs that search your data for expired content and set that content as expired, or you can add a simple `valid` function to your model and process only those where `m.valid()==True`

Comment: The idea of adding valid function is good but the problem is not how to get valid objects, it is how to set expired objects to expired status after their duration.

Comment: Set valid as a `@property`, now will have every model's`valid` property reflecting their actual status